# How to get Firebase JWT token to validate on server side in Latest Firebase IOS SDK

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying out new Firebase IOS SDK with firebase base authentication and my custom backend server . I have enabled username password authentication in firebase which works fine but I do not see any property on auth object which gives me the JWT token so that I can verify the requests on my custom backend server

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(singupusername.text!, password: singuppassword.text!) { (user, error) in
            print(user)
            print(error)
        }
```

the user does not have any property which gives me the firebase JWT token

Answer (score 2):

I figured out method to get access token in the latest SDK I used below method to get the latest token

```
 FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
            if let user = user{
                user.getTokenWithCompletion{
                    (data) in
                    print(data.0)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

the latest code should be

```
let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
currentUser?.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true) { idToken, error in
    if let error = error {
        // Handle error
        return;
    }

    // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
    // ...
    print("JWT is< \(idToken)>")
            
}
```

Comment: don't forget to import Firebase